# How to make ng test to fail on warnings

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I've just finished fixing several warnings on my unit/component tests of my Angular app, that run using `ng test` (with Karma/Jasmine).

This process can be quite time-consuming as it is not always obvious to spot which test case(s) is actually causing the warning(s).

So now that I don't have any more warnings, I'm wondering if there is a way to make `ng test` to automatically fail whenever there are any warnings.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this in `test.ts` or someplace where the tests get initialized.

```
console.warn = (message) => throw new Error(message);
```

I don't know if I would recommend this because warnings are just that warnings, but errors are errors and should be dealt with immediately. Where you would place this for just the tests can be tricky too.

Answer (score 2):

Define an extra file in your workspace root - called `karma.globals.js` for example which looks like:

```js
// add globals for karma test runs
console.warn = (message) => { throw new Error(message); };
```

Now include it in your root `karma.conf.js` like:

```js
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    
    // ...

    files: [
      join(__dirname, 'karma.globals.js')
    ]

    // ...
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and easy fix is a `beforeAll` block in your `test.ts` file. It replaces all console methods with an error function.

That way the tests will fail if you call `console.log` and you will know which ones.

If you still wanna use `console.log` within a unit being tested, then you could spy on it. But that's also bad due to shared global state.

Here's an example:

```
const errorFn = () => { throw new Error('No console logs!'); };
beforeAll(() => Object.keys(console).forEach((fn: string) => (console as any)[fn] = errorFn));
```

Answer (score 0):

In `test.ts` I monkey patched it like so to print also the stack trace in case of an error:

```
console.error = function (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void {
  const messages = [message, ...optionalParams];
  const output = messages?.map(x => x.hasOwnProperty('stack') ? x.stack : x);
  fail(`Test contained console error:\n\n${output.join('\n')}`);
};

console.warn = function (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void {
  console.error(message, ...optionalParams);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Where in the file? just at the bottom after **karma**.start()?

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer to the question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).